# Cannot Uninitialize Advise sink

Tags: c++, exchangewebservices, mapi

I'm trying to properly close my `MAPI` session and I noticed it could not be closed properly. I tried moving my `MAPIUnintialize()` function where the problem occurs and I noticed that my `lpMAPISession->Unadvise()` function fails with error 0x8004010f. Even when I tried unadvising right after my `lpMDB-> Advise()` instance.
This is my function:

```
hRes = HrGetOneProp(lpFolder, PR_ENTRYID, &prop);  
hRes = lpMDB-> Advise(prop->Value.bin.cb, (LPENTRYID)prop->Value.bin.lpb,fnevObjecCreated,
 *lpAdviseSink, &ulConnection);  
...  
...  

lpAdviseSink ->Release();  
lpMAPISession -> UnAdvise(ulConnection);
```

Comment: The error is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`. Does your app run a Windows message pump?

Comment: Yes, does it matter?

Comment: Yes, the notification system uses Windows messages. Are you doing this on multiple threads?

Comment: Yes, in general, my program is multithreaded although the advising and unadvising are happening in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `UnAdvise` on `IMAPISession`. But your advise sink is on `IMsgSTore` object.